# Unity3d - Need to hide a group of objects in the area

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rendering, augmented-reality, vuforia

I've already tried depthmask shaders and examined some other ideas, but it seems like it doesn't suit me at all. 
I'm making an AR game and I have a scene with a house and trees. All these objects are animated and do something like falling from the sky, but not all at once, but in sequence. For example, the house first, then trees, then fence etc.

(Plz, look at my picture for details) http://f2.s.qip.ru/bVqSAgcy.png

If user moves camera too far, he will see all these objects stucking in the air and waiting for their order to start falling, and it is not good. I want to hide this area from all sides (because in AR camera can move around freely) and make all parts visible only when each will start moving (falling down).

(One more screen) http://f3.s.qip.ru/bVqSAgcz.png

I thought about animation events, but there are too many objects (bricks, for example) and I can't handle all of them manually.

I look forward to your great advice ;)

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Hey, great that you found a solution on your own - did you know you can add your own answer post to your question? Please do so, and consider accepting it after the wait period (24 hours) passes!

Comment: 18 hours, to be more precise :)
OK)

Comment: Don't forget accepting your solution as the right one. _(Accepting an answer helps future visitors coming on this page)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the solution I chose. I've added this script to each object in composition. It stores object's position (in my case both world and local) at Start() and listening if it changes in Update(). So, if true, stop monitoring and set MeshRenderer in on state.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class RenderScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private MeshRenderer mr;
    private bool monitoring = true;
    private Vector3 posLocal;
    private Vector3 posWorld;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.enabled = false;
        posLocal = transform.localPosition;
        posWorld = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (monitoring)
        {
            if (transform.localPosition != posLocal || transform.position != posWorld)
            {
                monitoring = false;
                mr.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even my funny cheap сhinese smartphone is alive after this, so, I guess, it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable their(the objects that are gonna fall) mesh renderers and re active them when they are ready to fall.

See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshRenderer.html) for more details about mesh renderer.

Comment: I've already mentioned, there are too many objects, my unity even responds hardly if I open animation window. I can't manually set the time for mesh renderer when it must be on and don't know how to do this automaticaly.

Comment: what i've seen at your hierarchy you group your objects in a parent 'A' . You could try enabling and disabling the GameObject A  as @habsi said.

Comment: Not good enough. For example I have a group of bricks. There are dozens of objects. And bricks don't fall together, but one by one in a sequence. If I use a group, all these bricks will hang in the air for some time

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate your Object. You might use the camera viewport coordinates to get a y position outside the viewport. They start on the bottom left of the screen (0,0) and go to the top right of the screen (1,1). Convert them to worldspace coordinates. [Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html)

```
Vector3 outsideCamera = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 1.2f, 10.0f));
```

Now you can use the intended x and z positions of your object. Activate it when you want to drop it.

```
myObject.transform.position = new Vector3(myObject.transform.position.x, outsideCamera.y, myObject.transform.position.z);
```

Another thing you could additionally do is scaling the object from very small to its intended size when it is falling. This would prevent the object being visible before falling when the users point the camera upwards.

Comment: I have tooooo many objects (look at this: http://f3.s.qip.ru/bVqSAgcB.png - you have to scroll and scroll down to get the last object of the 3d model). So, I can't use any events. Turning on/off mesh renderers or changing scale of objects. Well, I can, but it will take very much time.
Maybe it's possible to monitor object position in Update function, however I'm not sure how it affects performance.

Comment: The number of objects should not be relevant. You can add a public list to your script to track the objects. Or you could tag them and get them at the start of your application.

In short you should use a manager Object that keeps track of all your objects and shows/hides them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**1-** Maybe you can use the **Camera** far clipping plane property.

Or you can even use 2 **Cameras** if you need to display let's say the landscape on one (which will not render the house + trees + ...) with a "big" far clipping plane and use a second one with *Depth only* clear flags rendering only the items (this one can have a smaller far clipping plane from what I understand).

**2-** Other suggestion I'd give you is adding the scale to your animation:

- set the scale to 0 on the beginning of animation
- wait for the item to be needed to fall down
- set the scale to 1 (with a transition if needed)
- make the item fall down

**EDIT:** the workaround you found is quite just fine too! But tracking only world position should be enough I think (saving a tiny amount of memory).

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: 1. Clipping plane can't help 'cas it is an AR game and camera doesn't have a fixed position.

2. I can't manage scale for myself 'cas animation window is not able to handle with so long list of objects. My 3d modeler uses 3d max and he said there are some problems with scaling objects (they don't have a fixed value as in unity)

3. I don't know why, but only world position is not working for some reason.